# Settings view with user text input

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm new to iOS development and trying to figure out how these in-app settings views are done where you can change your contact details and a few other settings.

My first attempt was a static table but I couldn't figure out how to override the cell content with a text input field. Is this the way to go? If yes, what's the easiest way to add a text input field to the cell that I can preset with the user data (coming from our server)?

[image]

Comment: For a static TVC, set the cell type to custom and you can drag out labels and fields as you need.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for me, I had the cell type set to basic. Do you want to put your comment in as an answer and I'll mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a static TVC, set the cell type to custom and you can drag out labels and fields as you need.